# How can I target a child class only if the first child has a specific class?

Tags: html, css, parent-child, parent

How can I target the ::before in the class .child-ccc only if the first child has the class .hovered?

Here is the HTML output:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child hovered">
        <div class="child-aaa"></div>
        <div class="child-aaa"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="child"></div>

    <div class="child-c">
        <div class="child-ccc">
            ::before
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried .child:first-child.hovered + .child-c .child-ccc:before

Comment: Try `.child:first-child.child-ccc:before`

Comment: @Spankied Thank you for leaving a comment. I don't think that will work as .child and .child-ccc cannot be in the same string. `.child-ccc` is a decendent of the sibling to `.child`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` selector only selects adjacent siblings but `child-c` isn't. So, you have to use `~`.

```css
.parent .child:first-child.hovered~.child-c .child-ccc::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1rem;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child hovered">
    <div class="child-aaa">aaa</div>
    <div class="child-aaa">aaa</div>
  </div>

  <div class="child">bbb</div>

  <div class="child-c">
    <div class="child-ccc">
      ccc
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting me on how to use `+` and `~`. Unfortunately, it's not targeting the first .child with `:first-child`. Do you think it's because my parent div is nested in other divs? I did not show that output on here for easier read.

Comment: @Ruby Update the question by adding how your HTML looks like

Comment: @Ruby Try prefixing `.parent` to increase the specificity.

Comment: Your answer has solved my question. Thank you! I'll forever use these selectors correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can achieve this by using advance CSS selectors. Try this code `.child.hovered ~ .child-c > child-ccc::before`
This symbol `~` means the sibling of `.child.hovered` class and `>` means direct child element.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I guess I should have mentioned that the class `.hovered` gets injected when user hovers over the divs. With that said, how can I target just the *first* .child when it has the `.hovered` class? Right now your code will target *all* .child that gets hovered over. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Selector `+` is `adjacent sibling combinator` it means if we write `img + p` it selects `Paragraphs that come immediately after any image` and the selector `~` is `General sibling combinator` it means if we use `img ~ p` it selects `Paragraphs that are siblings of and subsequent to any image`.

so in your problem instead of `+` you should use `~` to achieve your goal like this:

```
.child.hovered ~ .child-c .child-ccc::before{
    ... 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!! I guess I should have mentioned that the class `.hovered` gets injected when user hovers over the divs. With that said, how can I target *just the first* .child when it has the .hovered class? Right now your code will target *all* .child that gets hovered over. Hope that makes sense!